# How to get before first &nbsp

Tags: javascript, meteor

I get a text from a div but I  need to get before first &nbsp.How can I do.

Image.html

```
   <div class="progress-label">63951_1417323055238082_7899260806224854935_n.jpg&nbsp;
<span style="font-size: smaller; color: #333">59.4&nbsp;KB</span>
    </div>
```

I need to "63951_1417323055238082_7899260806224854935_n.jpg"

getImage.js

```
aracResimYolu=template.$(".progress-label").text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will extract out the image name,

```
var img_name = $(".progress-label").html().split("&nbsp")[0];
alert(img_name);
```

JsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ydzzhb0r/

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
var text = $(".progress-label").text();
aracResimYolu= text.substring(0, text.length-6);
```

or as @tibzon stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31770316/3793161), you can do this too:

```
aracResimYolu= $(".progress-label").html().split("&nbsp")[0];
```

Comment: But Text is change every upload image not static

Comment: It doesn't matter, it will work as long as you have a structure like `yourUrl&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `split(...)[0]` approach is to use `indexOf` and `substring`:

```
const html = $(".progress-label").html();
const index = html.indexOf("&nbsp");
const string = index === -1 ? html : html.substring(0, index);
```

This avoids unnecessarily creating arrays (not that it matters 99.999999% of the time).